# NS2 Package not located in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, package-management, software-installation, ns2

i have installed ns2 on ubuntu 12.04 and there never have been any problem. Now with 13.04, it gives this message "unable to locate the package: ns2" . Whether i try it through software centre or through terminal. same message.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Seems to exist in "universe": http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ns2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your server to main server in `Software and updates`. Then, run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ns2 nam xgraph
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Google chrome or if you have tried to install Google chrome, go to the software center->Edit->click on Software Sources
Then in the "Other Software" tab change the status of Google chrome to uncheck.
It worked for me like that.